# Error unable to open http://xxx/songs/xxx.mp3 in read mode

Tags: android, media-player

I have made a media player that plays mp3 file from the server. But when I try to play any song it gives me the following error.

```
5-30 18:23:13.305 308-647/? E/OmaDrmEngine: unable to open http://abc/songs/xxxxx.mp3 in read mode
05-30 18:23:13.923 309-1185/? E/MM_OSAL: FileSource::FileSource
05-30 18:23:13.923 309-1185/? E/MM_OSAL: FileSource::FileSource m_bEveryThingOK 1
05-30 18:23:13.923 309-1185/? E/MM_OSAL: MM_File_Create failed .Efs Error No -1 , File Name /data/mmosal_logmask.cfg , Mode 0
05-30 18:23:13.923 309-1185/? E/MM_OSAL: Open or read fail on /data/mmosal_logmask.cfg. Possible permission denied issue. Looking for /data/misc/media/mmosal_logmask.cfg
05-30 18:23:13.924 309-1185/? E/MM_OSAL: MM_File_Create failed .Efs Error No -1 , File Name /data/misc/media/mmosal_logmask.cfg , Mode 0
```

Can somebody help please

Comment: Either the file does not exist in the server or you are not allowed to read the file.

Comment: file do exist as i played the mp3 file directly on the server and i believe i can read the file too. bot how can i check that?

Comment: Any update on this issue? Having the same problem here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case file was not accessible. To test I used any song link available on google and replaced it with my link. It worked. So I realized the file was not accessible on the server.